# Trigger WebviewClient's onPageFInished() method manually in a single-page application

Tags: android, angularjs, android-webview

I have an application already running in production, the application has one module which is running on Andorid webview. It's a multi-pages website. Now I am converting that website into a single page Angular JS based website.

Everything is fine except one method for accessing some information from cookie which is written in on onPageFinished(). Now as you are aware onPage finished() won't be triggered in the middle of a single page architecture.

I am sure something on the either javascript or web which is triggering that method in Android WebviewClient as usual flow, I have searched on web and StackOverflow but could not find a way to trigger that method manually using some javascript methods or any other approach.